# Functional programming for ForLoop

Tags: java, lambda

I am new to functional programming and needs some sort of guidance of writing the below piece of code using java

```
    public List<sampleEntity> sampleLetter(List<String> sampleIds) {
    List<sampleEntity> lstsampleEntity = new ArrayList<>();

    //Wanted to have the below for loop written using functional programming
            for (String sampleId : sampleIds) {
                lstsampleEntity.add(sampleLetter(sampleId));
            }

        return lstsampleEntity;
   }
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt?

Comment: Check forEach() method.

Comment: @Evgenii no, `forEach` is not the right tool.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should try to write it yourself and then come back if you need help troubleshooting it after you've tried yourself.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return sampleIds.stream()
    .map(s -> sampleLetter(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the lambda could be written as a method reference (either `this::sampleLetter` or `TheClass::sampleLetter`); you don't show the method declaration of the overload, so I just used the lambda which works in either case.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I tried using the forEach and realized that there is something missing in my understanding which has actually prompted to ask this question